# Why eigen vector is so slow?

Tags: c++, eigen

I found that calculation of substracting two Eigen::Vector3f is slower than the substracting two strucutre.

I call 10000000 times subtraction between Eigen::Vector3f and self-defined structure. 
I found the speed of self-defined structure is 20 times faster then Eigen::Vector3f.

Here is my test code.

```
#include<Eigen/Eigen>
#include<iostream>
#include "timer.h"

struct Point {
    float x, y, z;
    Point Add(const Point& point) const {
        Point result = {
            x + point.x,
            y + point.y,
            z + point.z
        };
        return result;
    }
};

Eigen::Vector3f sub_eigen(const Eigen::Vector3f& vector_a,
                          const Eigen::Vector3f& vector_b) {
    Eigen::Vector3f result;
    result = vector_a - vector_b;
    return result;
};

Point sub_point(const Point& point_a,
                const Point& point_b) {
    Point result = point_a.Add(point_b);
    return result;
}


int main() {
    Eigen::Vector3f source_eigen(1.f, 1.f, 1.f);
    Eigen::Vector3f dest_eigen(1.f, 1.f, 1.f);
    Point point_a = {1.f, 1.f, 1.f};
    Point point_b = {1.f, 1.f, 1.f};
    int num_tests = 10000000;
    std::cout << "Caculate time:" << num_tests << "\n";
    Timer timer;
    timer.Tic();
    for (int i = 0; i < num_tests; i++) {
        Eigen::Vector3f result_eigen =
            sub_eigen(source_eigen, dest_eigen);
    }
    timer.Toc();
    std::cout << "Time[Eigen]:" << timer.TimeElapsed() << "\n";

    timer.Tic();
    for (int i = 0; i < num_tests; i++) {
        Point result_point =
            sub_point(point_a, point_b);
    }
    timer.Toc();
    std::cout << "Time[Point]:" << timer.TimeElapsed() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The result is following:

```
Caculate time:10000000
Time[Eigen]:3.3389
Time[Point]:0.163778
```

As you can see, the speed  of Eigen::Vector3f is nearly 20 times slower than self-defined structre.
Do I use eigen in wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eigen is very sensitive to optimization, for example on my system with `-O0`:

```
Caculate time:10000000
Time[Eigen]:6.80348
Time[Point]:0.275657
```

But with `-O3`:

```
Caculate time:10000000
Time[Eigen]:0.0128227
Time[Point]:0.0116121
```

Comment: Although it likely won't help here, you should also add `-march=native`, and you often gain a bit more performance by also adding `-DNDEBUG`.